# Given two specific vertices, how to get the subgraph between them in Titan?

Tags: gremlin, titan, nosql

We have millions of vertices and ten of millions of edges to form a directed graph. Does anybody know how to get the subgraph in Titan between two given vertices?

Answer (score 2):

TinkerPop provides two methods of subgraphing:

1. There is [`subgraph` step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#subgraph-step) and
2. There is [`subgraph` strategy](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_subgraphstrategy)

Use `subgraph` step to "pop off" a subgraph into a separate graph instance. You can see in the following example how the graph "g" is subgraphed into a new `Graph` instance of "knows" edges:

```
gremlin> subGraph = g.E().hasLabel('knows').subgraph('subGraph').cap('subGraph').next() //(1)
==>tinkergraph[vertices:3 edges:2]
gremlin> sg = subGraph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:3 edges:2], standard]
gremlin> sg.E() //(2)
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
```

You would use `Subgraph` strategy in cases where you want to traverse a subset of the graph only:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createTheCrew()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:14]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal().withStrategies(SubgraphStrategy.build().
           vertices(or(hasNot('location'),properties('location').count().is(gt(3)))).
           edges(hasLabel('develops')).
           vertexProperties(or(hasLabel(neq('location')),hasNot('endTime'))).create())
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:14], standard]
gremlin> g.V().valueMap(true)
==>[id:1,label:person,name:[marko],location:[santa fe]]
==>[id:8,label:person,name:[matthias],location:[seattle]]
==>[id:10,label:software,name:[gremlin]]
==>[id:11,label:software,name:[tinkergraph]]
gremlin> g.E().valueMap(true)
==>[id:13,label:develops,since:2009]
==>[id:14,label:develops,since:2010]
==>[id:21,label:develops,since:2012]
```

Based on the title of your question it sounds like you just want a graph of the two vertices with the edges between them. I suppose it sounds like you would want to use `subgraph` step. Of course, it seems even easier than that to get that result:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V(1).bothE().where(otherV().hasId(2))
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
```

Having the list of edges constitute a subgraph in a sense especially in the case of two known vertices.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Stephen Mallette! Is it possible to change to the commands of Titan  0.5.4? Currently, we do not have plan to upgrade to Titan 1.0.

Comment: There are no built in subgraph functions in TinkerPop 2.x and Titan 0.5.x. You'd have to write your own method of doing that. You can find the edges between two vertices pretty easily though: `g.v(1).bothE.as('x').bothV.retain([g.v(3)]).back('x')` copied from [gremlindocs.com](http://gremlindocs.spmallette.documentup.com/#finding-edges-between-vertices)

Comment: Good! We will try it in more detail. By the way, do you know how to get all cycles within a directed graph in Titan? Is there a built-in function or should we write our own method?